# When should we create new intent in wit.ai

Tags: wit.ai

When should I create new intent and when should I add new value to the existing intent ? In wit.ai documents, they didn't talk much about this.

EDIT: Let says I have command for a door. So is it better to have 1 intent door_command with values open_door, close_door, or have 2 intents open_door and close_door.

Comment: Do you have examples of what you are asking?

Comment: I have added an example into my post. Please check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One intent should do for your case as it is a toggle.

Comment: so if it has 4, 5 values, is it still ok ?

Comment: If the intent relates to the door then keep the same. open_door, close_door, halfwayopen_door. Create a new intent if something else like open_window, close_window